# Take screenshot with selenium in Fullscreen mode

Tags: python, selenium

I am taking a screenshot by using [selenium with no display](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.de/2011/07/python-taking-browser-screenshots-with.html). It's working but it would be nice if I could take a screenshot of the Fullscreen Browser (without Firefox Toolbar and so on, just the website). I tried the above code which should perform a F11 press. The code runs with no error, however Fullscreen is not working, so I guess the F11 command is somehow not executed. My OS is ubuntu.

Can somebody tell me how to take the screenshot in selenium in Fullscreen mode?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

ActionChains(browser).send_keys(Keys.F11).perform()

browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')

browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: What if you find the `body` element (`body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')`) and send keys to it (`ActionChains(body).send_keys(Keys.F11).perform()`)?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: Ok, what if just `body.send_keys(Keys.F11)`?

Comment: The code is running with no error, but still no fullscreen screenshot.

Comment: Well most modern browsers sport an api call to go fullscreen: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Answer (score 1):

just select one element on the page and send the keys ,

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("your_element")
elem.send_keys(Keys.F11)
```

make sure that element is loaded in DOM.It worked for me.